# Regular load of data via CSV into django data model

Tags: python, django, database, csv, model

I am writing a web application that will regularly pull data in the CSV format from different sources from the internet. This data will then be aggregated using django and made visible via a frontend so the data can be manipulated. Is it better to create a function that will convert the CSV file into a jason format and then loaded into the django model or is it better to directly load the CSV content into a django model. I was thinking that by first converting it to jason the data could be reused by another app at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways:

- **Create Django command and run it manually:**
  When you want to load the new  data by running a simple command as running Django server (python manage.py YouCommand) read [Django docs](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands.html) for more information
- **Using Cron job:** When you want to load the new data automatically. read [Django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) for more information
- **Add a button in your template:** when clicked run a views.py method to load the new data to the database
- **...**

**PS**: I think you don't have to convert the file CSV to JSON format.
(try to read carefully the docs of pandas, CSV.. packages about this)